# Change all references to other database in a view

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in Sql Server. It has many views and these have references to other database (same server).
How can I change all references of the views to other database? Do I have to do one by one?

This is the code of a view:
SELECT        id, tipo, matricula, descripcion
FROM            DATABASE1.dbo.t_vehiculo

I want to change the reference "DATABASE1" to "DATABASE2" in all views at once.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique database name (one that is not like any other text in your view), you could do it like this.

```sql
DECLARE     @ObjectName     nvarchar(128)
DECLARE     @ViewCode       nvarchar(max)
DECLARE     @Sql            nvarchar(max)

DECLARE     CurView 
CURSOR FOR  SELECT      OBJECT_NAME(object_id),  REPLACE(COM.text, 'DATABASE1.dbo.', 'DATABASE2.dbo.')
            FROM        sys.views           AS VWS
            INNER JOIN  sys.syscomments     AS COM
                ON      COM.id              = VWS.object_id
            WHERE       COM.text            LIKE '%DATABASE1.dbo.%'

OPEN CurView

FETCH NEXT  FROM    CurView
            INTO    @ObjectName, @ViewCode
WHILE       @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
            SET         @Sql = 'DROP VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName)
            EXEC        (@Sql) 
            EXEC        (@ViewCode)
            FETCH NEXT  FROM    CurView
                        INTO    @ObjectName, @ViewCode
END

CLOSE CurView
DEALLOCATE CurView
```

I have not tested the code, so be careful and first perform your own test before executing it on your live system.

Comment: Thanks!! simply indicate a small error this "WHERE       COM.text            LIKE 'DATABASE1.dbo.'" would be "WHERE       COM.text            LIKE '%DATABASE1.dbo.% "

Comment: Sorry I detected another error. After the code "EXEC (@ViewCode)" is necessary add this: "FETCH NEXT  FROM CurView INTO @ObjectName, @ViewCode".
Regards

Comment: WARNING: This might revert your database as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186293.aspx COM.text is the original definition and if any of your view have been altered these changes will not be reflected.

Comment: Example from select to prove my point :

first column: Garbage_Routes_with_GIS 


start of seconds column: CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Garbage_Routes_with_GISLINK]


The view had been renamed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not prepared for this ahead of time, then manual editing one-by-one is your most likely choice.  The only "bulk" option available would be to use SSMS to script all of your Views to one file/query session, then do a search and replace on the DB name.  Unfortunately, depending on the database name and your View's code, that could be pretty dicey.

What I do is to define all of my out-of-database references in Synonyms.  Then I write my Views so that they only reference the Synonyms, and never the external database directly.  Now, if the external DB changes, I can use a simple automated procedure to change all of the Synonyms at once.